# Set Windows Explorer column width to less than 100 pixels

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

I want to further reduce the width of the "File extension" column:

[image]

I can Right click > More > Highlight "File extension" > but if I wish to change "100" to anything less, Windows Explorer doesn't allow it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't upgraded to Win11 yet, but if folders still save their views under the registry key:
`HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

Then the following **PowerShell** will shrink the width of the `File Extension` column to a preset width (`$NewWidth`) in all saved views that display the `File Extension` column.

You then have the option of setting any of those as a custom template for its associated *`FolderType`* by using `Apply to Folders`.

```
$NewWidth           = 0x35
$Bags               = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$ExtPropKey         = [PSCustomObject]@{
                          'FmtID' = [GUID]'e4f10a3c-49e6-405d-8288-a23bd4eeaa6c'
                          'PID'   = 100
                      }
$PropKeyAsBytes     = $ExtPropKey.FmtID.ToByteArray() + [BitConverter]::GetBytes($ExtPropKey.PID)
$Encoder            = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(28591)
$RegEx              = [Regex]$Encoder.GetString( $PropKeyAsBytes )

gci $Bags -Recurse |
    ? PSChildName -like '{*}' |
    ? Property -contains  'ColInfo' |
ForEach-Object{
    $ColInfoAsText   = $Encoder.GetString(( $ColInfoAsBytes = $_.GetValue('ColInfo') ))

    If ( ( $ColumnPresent = $RegEx.Match( $ColInfoAsText ) ).Success )
    {        
        $WidthOffset                  = $ColumnPresent.Index + 0x14
        $ColInfoAsBytes[$WidthOffset] = $NewWidth
        $Splat = @{
            'Path'    = $_.PSPath
            'Name'    = 'ColInfo'
            'Value'   = $ColInfoAsBytes
        }
        Set-ItemProperty @Splat
    }
}
```